# How to drag and drop elements horizontally and vertically in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, ncurses-cdk

I have created drag and elements with the help of `cdk-angular` (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) but the problem is I can only drag and drop the elements either horizontally or vertically.

Suppose I have an array like this.

```
completed = [{
      name: 'HTML',
    },
    {
      name: 'CSS',
    },
    {
      name: 'Angular',
    },
    {
      name: 'React',
    },
    {
      name: 'Vue',
    }
];
```

and in Html I am using it in the following way

```
<div class="list"
 cdkDropList
 #todoList="cdkDropList"
 cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
 [cdkDropListData]="completed"
 [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
 (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
                  
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options;let i = index">
   <div class="mat-card" cdkDrag>
    <p>{{option.name}}</p>
   </div>
  </ng-container>

</div>
```

Here is the result
[image]

After adding `cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"` I can drag horizontally, and when I remove it I can drag it vertically.

But when the options are big then I need to wrap it and then I need horizontal and vertical drag together. Can anyone put some lights on it. I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will allow you to drag both vertical and horizontal

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" gutterSize="10px">
  <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index"
    [colspan]="card.cols"
    [rowspan]="card.rows"
  >
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i">
      <div
        cdkDrag
        (cdkDragEntered)="entered($event)"
        [cdkDragData]="i"
        class="card"
        [style.backgroundColor]="'#b9d4f6'"
      >
        <span>{{ card.title }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

TS

```
    export class GridComponent {
  entered($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
    
    console.log($event.item.data, $event.container.data);
    moveItemInArray(this.cards, $event.item.data, $event.container.data);
  }

  @ViewChildren(CdkDropList) dropsQuery: QueryList<CdkDropList>;

  drops: CdkDropList[];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dropsQuery.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.drops = this.dropsQuery.toArray();
    });
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      this.drops = this.dropsQuery.toArray();
      console.log(this.drops);
    });
  }

  /** Based on the screen size, switch from standard to one column per row */
  cards = [
    { title: 'Card 1', cols: 3, rows: 1 },
    { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
    { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
    { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
    { title: 'Card 5', cols: 2, rows: 1 },
    { title: 'Card 6', cols: 2, rows: 1 },
  ];
}
```

css

```
    .card {
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px; */
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .more-button {
    float: right;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  .cdk-drop-list {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-preview {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-animating {
    transition: unset;
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-placeholder {
    display: none;
  }
```